# Django REST serializer property match to property of another class

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a serializer for a model called `Posts` that I can use to create a `Posts` object.  The `Posts` class has a few properties, one of them being `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`.

I want to be able to send a POST request to the view with a body like

```json
{
    "username": "myUserName"
}
```

or even

```json
{
    "user": "myUserName"
}
```

and have it tie the new post it makes to that user.
I know I can do this

```py
class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['user']
```

but I have to provide the userId instead of the userName

The User class does have a username field already and it is unique.
Normally for a GET request I would just use `SerializerMethodField` and make a method to transform the thing however I want, but I don't think it works with creating from a POST request

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how great this is, but it's what I did and it works.

```py
class CreatePostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.initial_data['username'])
        new_post = Posts.objects.create(
            user=user
        )
        return new_post

    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['user']
```

EDIT:  After digging a bit more I found that this works also, without overriding `create`.

```py
user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='username', queryset=User.objects.all())
```